# How to set max_receive_message_length globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc

I am using grpc-dynamic-gateway package and it uses the grpc package as a client. Im trying to figure out how I can set `max_receive_message_length` globally on the grpc object I require in my script?

```
const grpc = require('grpc');

grpc.max_receive_message_length = 1024 * 1024 * 100; // <-- this does not work, how can I do this?

app.use('/', grpcGateway(
  ['api.proto'],
  '0.0.0.0:5051',
  grpc.credentials.createInsecure(),
  true,
  process.cwd(),
  grpc // This is being passed to the middleware..id like it to have the option above set on it
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The change needs to be made directly in the grpc-dynamic-gateway package. In index.js on line 77 change:

```
getPkg(clients, pkg, true)[svc] = new (getPkg(protos[si], pkg, false))[svc](grpcLocation, credentials)
```

to

```
getPkg(clients, pkg, true)[svc] = new (getPkg(protos[si], pkg, false))[svc](grpcLocation, credentials, {
     "grpc.max_receive_message_length": 1024 * 1024 * 1000,
     "grpc.max_send_message_length": 1024 * 1024 * 1000
})
```

Im not sure if this is the only way to fix this but it worked for me. Also obviously adjust the message sizes to a more appropriate value for yourself. 1000mb is probably excessive.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this response in their github issues](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8098#issuecomment-248700348), you have to set this when you instantiate the server, as it is a server option:

```
var server = new grpc.Server({'grpc.max_receive_message_length': 1024*1024*100})
```

Comment: I did try this in place of `grpc.max_receive_message_length = 1024 * 1024 * 100` and it didnt work. I have a grpc server running with that parameter set however I think the grpc-dynamic-gateway is a client and the parameters need to be set there somehow. the grpc const thats defined and passed to the gateway needs to have those options modified.